# Internet Explorer 10 FCKEditor problems

Tags: asp-classic, ckeditor, fckeditor, internet-explorer-10

Hello Stackoverflow community.

Since the release of Windows 8 and thus, Internet Explorer 10, FCKEditor refuses to function with IE10. With the latest patches, Firefox 17 and Chrome work just fine with it.

I know FCKEditor is old, so I was thinking of moving to CKeditor but it seems, its implementation for classic asp webpages doesnt work with IE10 as well.

Any suggestions, on how to fix the problem, or any other editors (with the functionality of the above two editors) would be appreciated(classic asp only).

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor should work with IE10.

Maybe there are some problems with it at the moment (I tested it briefly some time ago), but given that it's a supported version (opposed to the status of FCKeditor), if you file bugs reporting the problems they should be fixed eventually.

Comment: OK then. Thank you very much for your direct answer :)